# How to update animation effects using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am trying to update a div content that is animating using `slideInleft` animation class from animation.css library and after 2 secs I am trying to update the effect by `slideLeftout` class.

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function showText{
var txt= data; // my data is an array with 5 values
$("#text").empty().append(txt[i].value).addClass('slideInLeft');
},2000);
$("#text").empty().append(txt[i].value).addClass('slideOutLeft');
```

Comment: To do your 3-stage animation you could trigger a jquery animation queue: `.animate( {left:'+=100}, 1000).delay(2000).animate( {left:'-=100}, 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

Add **animated** like this:

```
.addClass('animated slideInLeft')
```

But I recommand you to use this alternative (jQuery plugin): https://github.com/craigmdennis/animateCSS/blob/master/README.md

**More easy to implement and customize effect**

Comment: I already had animated class in my mark up like Pedro had. you can his markup below

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  $('#text').text('hello').addClass('slideInLeft');

  setTimeout(function () {
      $('#text').text('goodbye').removeClass('slideInLeft').addClass('slideOutRight');
  }, 2000);
  
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="text" class="animated"></div>
```

Comment: I am trying to to use slideInleft slideOutleft for all my even index values and slideInright and slideOutright for my odd index values